# How can you move a folder to one folder-level lower?

Tags: unix, command-line-interface

I have a folder Math at /cs/.../topology/mathematics/Math.

I tried the following unsuccessfully at the mathematics folder.

```
mv Math/ ..
```

**How can you move the folder Math to /cs/.../topology/ in terminal?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mv Math/ ../` although `mv Math/ ..` works too on one Linux system at the Uni.